# user rights needed for texlive install

Tags: texlive, installing

This is an update of my earlier question today. That title ("user rights to /usr/share") was unfortunately misleading.

I have a single user system, so I'm a sysadmin by default. Translation: I do not know Linux well enough to do a TeX Live install safely.

I've used TeX Live for several years, but always installed it as `sudo`. My OS is Ubuntu 19.04. I'd now like to do the TeX Live install as a regular user, because that's what the TeX Live documentation recommends. Let's call that user `Bob`.

After downloading `install-tl-unx.tar.gz` and extracting the `install-tl` script, I start the installation as user, by running: `perl install-tl -gui`. I get a permissions error saying that `Bob` cannot install to `/usr/local/texlive/2019`.

Here's my question. What is the Linux statement, I need to execute as `sudo` to give me the rights needed to complete this installation?

Answer (score 3):

Update 29-Jun-2019:

executing the following statement as sudo allowed me (as Bob) to complete the texlive install:

sudo setfacl -m u:bob:rwx /usr/local

Perhaps this will help someone sometime.

I've not yet had time to determine whether it solves my original problem (strangeness in access to fonts).

Thanks to all who responded to the post. I now consider it "answered" , unless someone can think of a better answer to the question.

Comment: If you want to install TeXlive 2019 in your system then download the complete package in .iso format by clicking on this link https://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/ctan/systems/texlive/Images/texlive2019.iso to install Texlive in gui mode you need to install perltk for your Ubuntu system @gml